# How do I include part of my code into 'yield'?

Tags: python, scrapy, nested-loops, yield

Thank you for your time!

Each products, sometimes have more than one model. I got the model 'name' and 'price' of the respective models within a single product via a for loop.

But, how do I 'transfer' these details to the 'yield' section along with other variables of that same product? Below is my attempt, but i am not getting it correct. How do I edit the code, so that, it could record more than one models (along with the price) within a same product, wherever applicable:

```
    for i in resp['item']['models']:
        if i['name'] is not None:
            model = i['name']
            model_pricing = i['price']


    yield{
        'product': resp.get('item').get('name'),
        'rating': resp.get('item').get('item_rating').get('rating_star'),
        'review numbers': resp.get('item').get('cmt_count'),
        'viewcount': resp.get('item').get('view_count'),
        'likes': resp.get('item').get('liked_count'),
        'model_pricing': model_pricing,
        'model': model,
        'location': resp.get('item').get('shop_location')
        }
```

Comment: You should not split model attributes in two separate lists (name & price). The original data structure is better than what you are trying to create.

Comment: @trincot, so, I  should use include the yield within the loop for each model?

Comment: Is the indentation of the code here the same as in your original code? The `yield` here is not part of the loop, while you probably meant it to be.

Comment: Some other things that would be extremely useful here: An example of some sample input, the current (incorrect) output, and the expected (desired) output from that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep your yield inside for loop and if statement.
You can try as follows:

```
for i in resp['item']['models']:
    if i['name'] is not None:
        model = i['name']
        model_pricing = i['price']

        yield {
            'product': resp.get('item').get('name'),
            'rating': resp.get('item').get('item_rating').get('rating_star'),
            'review numbers': resp.get('item').get('cmt_count'),
            'viewcount': resp.get('item').get('view_count'),
            'likes': resp.get('item').get('liked_count'),
            'model_pricing': model_pricing,
            'model': model,
            'location': resp.get('item').get('shop_location')
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not split model attributes in two separate lists (name & price). The original data structure is better than what you are trying to create.

You should make one `models` attribute (I suggest a plural) in your yielded dictionary, and let it be a list with name/price pairs. Those pairs could be either tuples -- or some other data structure (a custom class instance, named tuple, dictionary...):

```py
yield {
    # ... other attributes ...
    'models': [(model['name'], model['price']) for model in resp['item']['models']],
}
```

Comment: tq! it worked! I learnt something new and corrected my mistake. I however, prefer the method below by @fazlul. But thank you very much! I appreciate it

Comment: OK. Just to repeat that it is bad practice to separate attributes about a (model) object over two lists, where things relate when they are at the same index. OOP means that you keep things together that belong together (model name & price).